# returning a value from a function thats passed in as an argument

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow the async question/guide on this page, specifically the answer that is "**If you're not using jQuery in your code, this answer is for you**" in this question: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but I can't seem to get the value to return to the `var`.

```
function maxYvalue2(whendone) {
  Rpt_scn_cost_v.find({
    filter: {
      where: {
        scenario_id: $stateParams.id
      }
    }
  }).$promise.then(function(response) {
    var maxYvalue = 0
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      currMaxYvalue = parseFloat(response[i].cur_cost) + parseFloat(response[i].tgt_cost);
      if (currMaxYvalue > maxYvalue) {
        maxYvalue = currMaxYvalue
      };
    }
    console.log("y3: " + maxYvalue)
    whendone(maxYvalue);
    return maxYvalue;
  });
  return maxYvalue;
};

function onComplete(maxYvalue1) {

  mxVal = maxYvalue;

  console.log("mx: " + mxVal)

  return mxVal;

};

var yVal = maxYvalue2(onComplete);
console.log("fnc: " + yVal);
```

but `yVal` is still showing up as undefined...I followed the previous question/answer but still can't get the output thats in the guide....

I'm trying to follow this structure mentioned in the code:

```
function onComplete(a){ // When the code completes, do this
    alert(a);
}

function getFive(whenDone){ 
    var a;
    setTimeout(function(){
         a=5;
         whenDone(a);
    },10);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
getFive(onComplete);
```

am I following the right part of the response in the reference question?

Comment: Are you sure you have gone through the question you referred? It's a long answer that explains everything there. PS: as a side suggestion - learn how to indent, at the moment it's near to impossible to see the hierarchy in your code.

Comment: yes...I'm specifically following the "If you're not using jQuery in your code, this answer is for you" response...I can't seem to figure out whats wrong...please note that I'm a n00b at javascript so I'm trying to learn as I go...

Comment: Not sure why you mentioned jquery at all, please re-read the checked answer once again. Entirely.

Comment: @zerkms  thats the title of the response, right? "If you are not using jQuery.." which I'm not, so shouldn't I follow that one?

Comment: If you have read the answer entirely - you would have known it has nothing to do with jquery. It's unclear what kind of help you're looking for if you are lazy to read the link that contains the answer for you.

Comment: @zerkms  I know it doesn't have anything to do with jQuery....Im just trying to follow the guide that has jQuery in the title in the referenced question...I'm not referrring to jQuery, the question in the link has a title that has the word jQuery in it...I'm trying to be as specific as possible on what i"m doing and what I'm referring to

Comment: How so? What exactly have you done as per that advice?

Comment: The point is that your code is nothing like what the answer you're referring to would instruct you to do, so it's really hard to say anything other than "read the answer again."

Comment: I'm following this part of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/2061886..and specifically the part where it says `One possible solution to this problem is to code re-actively `...I'm structured my code to follow that but am not getting the same behavior.

Comment: "I'm structured my code to follow that but am not getting the same behavior." --- no you have not. See that they don't use `return`, at all. And never use any returned values anywhere.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. I mean, it's the same question and the code has literally the same problem.

Comment: I made an edit to show what I'm following...if I'm following the wrong part...let me know and I'll delete this question

Comment: Your problem is that (for some reason) you're looking at the return value of `maxYvalue2`. That's pointless because it returns `undefined`.

Comment: The main idea of software engineering is not that you're following some instructions/guides/tutorials. You need to understand *the problem*, then understand how the solution works, then to apply the knowledge for your particular case.

Comment: Maybe you've confused yourself with your choice of identifiers. You have a function called `maxYvalue2`, two different variables called `maxYvalue`, a variable called `maxYvalue1`, and a variable called `mxVal`. Half of these are globals (for no good reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises don't make code synchronous. You'll never be able to immediately return the value from `maxYvalue2`. Just return the promise instead:

```
function maxYvalue2() {
    return Rpt_scn_cost_v.find({filter: { where: {scenario_id: $stateParams.id}}}).$promise.then(function(response){
        var maxYvalue = 0
        for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            var currMaxYvalue = parseFloat(response[i].cur_cost) + parseFloat(response[i].tgt_cost);
            if (currMaxYvalue > maxYvalue) {
                maxYvalue = currMaxYvalue
            };
        }
        console.log("y3: " + maxYvalue)
        return maxYvalue;
    });
}

maxYvalue2().then(function onComplete(yVal) {
    console.log("fnc: " + yVal);
});
```